# Flexbox grid columns - Equal height child elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a column layout using flexbox grid and I would like all child elements of each column to be equal in height across all.

Current HTML:

```
<div class="row middle-xs center-xs">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 benefitFeatures">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also done a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgt6y13u/4/) for this

As you can see in the fiddle, I want to have all blue boxes same height and even the UL list to be same height so all would have an equal starting point.

I have tried using flex grow but no success. Any ideas how to make this work ?

Comment: I can't load your jsFiddle!

Comment: @Andyjm - It seems al jsfiddle is giving a 503 service error

Comment: There is no mechanism for equalising heights in flexbox that do not share a parent element. It's strictly a two-dimensional layout method.

Comment: If you want rows of equal heights...then use **rows**. That's what they are for.

Comment: I've had similar issues in grid layout works - hard to advise as JSfiddle looks like it's down, but containing divs and their children forced to 100% height was my solution

Comment: @Andyjm - seems to be back up

Comment: @JonyMurinko working solution posted below

Answer (score 0):

First you need to separate  the your heading with other columns.

I have add one div`.row-eq-height` with flex-box for that.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
.row-eq-height [class*="col-"] {  
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row middle-xs center-xs">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class=" row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 benefitFeatures">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Working Fiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wgt6y13u/5/)

Comment: This is breaking the responsiveness of columns falling underneath each other on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Solution here https://jsfiddle.net/wgt6y13u/6/

Just used a container wrap 'boxes' for the row of boxes, and added box-wrap class to each box element. These new classes just use basic flexbox alignment

```
.boxes {
  display: flex;
}
.box-wrap {
  align-self: flex-start
}
```

Comment: This broke the column layout responsiveness of flexboxgrid tho